# MVC 5 form doesn't POST to an [AllowAnonymous] method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to create a login form for my MVC 5 project. I've already got authentication working, so my controller is decorated with `[Authorize]`. When I launch my project, I am rightly directed to my anonymous Login action:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have setup my POST form in this view. The generated HTML looks fine.

I then add a new method that should accept the form submission:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    ...
```

I have found that when I submit a form, my first `Login` method is called -- apparently a redirect caused by some authentication issues. (A Fiddler trace shows that my form, while POST, gets sent to /Login?key=*myKeyHere* instead of being POSTed to /Login with key=*myKeyHere* as a form entry. Further, if I change my authentication's redirect URL from /Login to /SomethingElse, a form submission gets me redirected to /SomethingElse instead of posting it to /Login.)

If I remove `[Authorize]` from my controller, my form submission goes through just fine.

It doesn't appear to be an issue with my two methods being the same name (`Login`), as I can rename the method that accepts a POST, change my form's action, and submit to that, and I am redirected to my GET login page again.

What do I have to do to post a form to an `[AllowAnonymous]` method?

**Update to include my View**
My view already uses a POST action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("key", string.Empty, new { @class = "input_centered", id = "key_text"})
    <input type="submit" id="key_submit" class="enter" name="submit" value="Enter" />
}
```

The generated HTML looks good:

```
<form action="/Login" method="post">
<input class="input_centered" id="key_text" name="key" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="key_enter" class="enter" name="submit" value="Enter" />
```

Comment: If you create a new MVC Application, the template creates a Login POST action like you are trying to achieve.  Maybe looking through that can help you.  Can you show your form being submitted?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using FormCollection object, it is too broad and MVC engine can not construct or map  (de-serialise) your posted data to FormCollection object therefore can't find any matching Action for post. Try to convert your FormCollection into a serializable object.

eg.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
```

Comment: My code works fine when I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute. Why would this be an issue of complexity?

Comment: I had similar issue before that's why I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You login form is just collecting the data to allow you to be authorized. When you post the form it goes to POST method (with the `[Authorize]` attribute), sees that your not yet authorized (at this stage no method has actually been called to authorize you), and immediately redirects you back to the login page, thus creating an endless loop.

Your POST method needs the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and then in that method you perform you authorization logic. From now on your authorized and can access other action methods that are marked with `[Authorize]`.

Comment: My second method (`public ActionResult Login(FormCollection formCollection)`) _is_ setup as `[AllowAnonymous]`. Perhaps it's not registering somehow?

Comment: I just copied your code into a new project and it works fine (hits the POST method).

Comment: Stephen: Are you restricting controller-level access with `[Authorize]`?

Comment: Yes I did. But your razor code generates `<form action="/Home/Login" method="post">` (not `action="/Login"` which would post to the `Index` method of `LoginController`) so something else is wrong here (and if your using `FormCollection` for this, you really need to rethink what your doing.